# Can a function that satisfies the condition $f''(x) = a \cos f(x) $ and $(f'(x))^2 = b \sin f(x)$ be found?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can I find a function that satisfies the following conditions?
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f''(x)    &=&  a \cos f(x) \tag{1}   \\  
(f'(x))^2 &=&  b \sin f(x) \tag{2}   \\
f(x)      &>& 0            \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}$$

That's what I have tried so far:

*(I will denote the function with $y = f(x)$ and its derivatives as $y'$, $y''$. Also, for simplicity purposes we will let $a=b=1$)*

So:

1. Squaring both and adding because I noted that $y''$ and $(y')^2$ are on the unit circle therefore resulting in:

$$(y'')^2 + (y')^4 = 1$$

2. By using the chain rule to get 
   $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d(y')}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} \\
   \iff y'  \frac {d}{dy} (\sqrt {\sin {y}}) = \cos y \\
   \iff y' \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\sin y}} \cos y = \cos y \\
   \iff \int \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\sin y}} dy = x + c $$
3. Dividing $(1)$ and $(2)$ where $y' \neq 0$:
   $$- \frac{y''}{(y')^2} = - \cot y \iff \bigg (\frac{1}{y'} \bigg )' = - \cot y$$
4. Combine the new equations that were derived to get $(y'')^2 + (4 \sin y)^2 = 1$ and $\frac {d} {dx} (\frac{1}{2 \sqrt { \sin y}}) = - \cot y$

Comment: This is not a good idea! Okay, f''(x) = cos(f(x)) is a differential equation, but it is also non-linear and transcendental. So it is way beyond the reach of standard mathematics to solve this. Though there exists a trivial solution, namely one where f'' = 0. This yields: f(x) = pi/2.

Comment: Hm, this came from physics while investigating the motion of a pivoting rod where the angular velocity and momentum are changing due to changes in torque. I wanted to find an equation for the rotating angle with respect to time $\theta (t)$ (treated as $f(x)$). I also know that the integral above is an elliptic one (do you mean this with "beyond")?

Comment: A differential equation usually contains terms with x, y, x^2, y^2, x*y or perhaps cos(x). Put you chose cos(y) !!! This makes things very much more complicated. I don't think you realized that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(f')^2=b\sin f$ then $2f''f'=b(\cos f)f'$ hence $b=2a$, which we assume from now on, and the second equation implies the first one. (Note that choosing $a=b=1$ "for simplicity purposes" actually replaces a system with solutions for well chosen values of the parameters, by a system with no solution.)

If $b=2a$ is positive, then $$f(t)=\tfrac12\pi-2\,\mathrm{am}\left(c-\tfrac12\sqrt{b}t \mid 2\right),$$ for some constant $c$, where $\mathrm{am}(\ \mid\ )$ denotes the [Jacobi amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html).